# Neither LOAD DATA LOCAL..REPLACE or INSERT..ON DUPLICATE are working. Something wrong with my table structure?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, load-data-infile, insert-into

I'm loading files into a table with php. I create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table (
`id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`order` INT DEFAULT 0,
`data` VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE KEY,
`cur_timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW())"
```

And fill it from a text file like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
INFILE '".$file ."' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE $table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^' 
(`order`,`data`)"
```

I've also tried reading the file into an array and just using an INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY

```
INSERT INTO $table (`order`,`data`)
VALUES ($parts[0],'$parts[1]') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `order` = '$parts[0]'
```

In both cases if data is the the same in the new and old record but order is different it INSERTs. I expect it to UPDATE if data is the same. I expect my tables not set up properly, but can't see what the problem is. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't UPDATE when data matches?

Comment: Is there an error message? What does it say?

Comment: You could try DESCRIBE table_name to make sure you actually have got what you think you've got.

Comment: @Pekka - there's no error message, it creates a new record even though the unique key data was the same in the new record

Comment: Field Type Null Key Default Extra
id int(11) NO PRI NULL auto_increment
order int(11) YES   0  
data varchar(200) YES UNI NULL  
cur_timestamp timestamp YES CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: didn't keep my formatting.. data is UNI KEY, order insn't- so to me it looks like I'm getting what I'm expecting.

Comment: Can you try this without the primary key?

Comment: I did a test last night where I made data the primary. But I'll try removing id completely

Comment: Ok I created the table same as in my original que, but without the id field. I tried creating one time with data defined exactly as above and one time with 

    `data` VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY

In both cases this sql

INSERT INTO test_4 (`order`,`data`) 
  VALUES (301,'test6') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE `order` = '301'

INSERT'd a record even though there was a record in the table where data = 'test6', order = 299

I just used phpmyadmin to test this case. I checked structure of test_4 and data is PRIMARY..

Comment: Hmm.. If I start from scratch and run the statements in phpmyadmin it works as expected. 

The main difference there would be that the CREATE TABLE is being run in pma..  
@pekka thanks for the help.

Comment: @integris strange! Could it be that there are subtle differences in `data` (e.g. line breaks or white space)?

Comment: Apparently.. after bringing both the create and insert out from pma. I got it to work. I'm trying to figure out exactly what the difference was. This looked like the main difference: VALUES ($parts[0],/'$parts[1]/') but that sometime seems to give an error. I'll post the working code in a little.

Comment: The above is wrong.. I found through a bunch more testing that I had two different test cases. The original issue always happens if record I expect to be replaced has the DEFAULT value ( 0 ). If order = default then record is INSERTed. Even though data matched.. I guess I'll make this its own question

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to insert data including primary key- here id. In that case if old and new id are same, then data will be replaced- otherwise not. But your PK is AUTO_INC, so alternatively you can use an unique index column like `order` or anything else. For reference, please see - [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html)
2. To print an array content, you need to use {} like

   "INSERT INTO $table (`order`,`data`)
   VALUES ({$parts[0]},'{$parts[1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html)}') 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `order` = '{$parts[0]}'"

   or concatenation

Hope this may help you

Sadat

Comment: I guess I thought I was using "an unique index column" since data is set to UNIQUE. I'm not sure what you're suggesting I change.

I put the {} around the arrays, didn't notice any change in output. I've definitely been reading the references. I must me missing something.

Comment: I think @integris is right: according to the docs, ON DUPLICATE KEY is supposed to work for simple UNIQUE columns as well. Strange.

Comment: both of you are right, i have missed that "UNIQUE KEY" of `data` column :(